Can not deserialize Spring Boot WebClient response to Java POJO
I have an API which responds with the following JSON data
{
  "message": "...",
  "status": "OK",
  "data": {
    "host": "10.200.100.1",
    "port": 8080
  }
}

I am trying to request this API and store the result into a ConfigServiceResponse Java class.
@Data
public class ConfigServiceResponse {
  private String message;
  private String status;
  private SampleHostConfig data;
}

@Data
public class SampleHostConfig {
  private String host;
  private int port;
}

Here is the code that I am using to make a request
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;

WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder().baseUrl(baseUrl).build();
webClient
  .get()
  .uri("/config?configId=" + configId + "&configVersion=" + configVersion)
  .retrieve()
  .bodyToMono(ConfigServiceResponse.class)
  .block();

I am getting the following error when i am executing the above code
Caused by: org.springframework.web.reactive.function.UnsupportedMediaTypeException: Content type 'application/json' not supported for bodyType=com.w3worker.ConfigServiceResponse

While if i try to deserialise it into String, it’s working fine. Not able to understand, what is causing the issue here.

pom.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.w3worker</groupId>
    <artifactId>config-service-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>22</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>22</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webflux -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webflux</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
            <version>1.18.30</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>


For me the pom.xml looks strange. Why don't you use the spring boot starters? You can generate the correct pom with https://start.spring.io/

I just need to use webflux, but the question is different.

The spring boot starters are the answer to your question. They are designed to provide all the auto configuration and related dependencies.

The Spring Boot starters are the answer to your question. They are designed to provide all the auto configuration and related dependencies.
Using https://start.spring.io/ you will get the correct pom.xml for a Spring Boot project with Webflux.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.w3worker</groupId>
    <artifactId>config-service-client</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>config-service-client</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>22</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>


Try to set acceptable media types using accept method:
webClient
  .get()
  .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  .uri("/config?configId=" + configId + "&configVersion=" + configVersion)
  .retrieve()
  .bodyToMono(ConfigServiceResponse.class)
  .block();

